# Collation conflict ERROR ,Set collation for stored procedure as database default

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

How can I set for COLLATION for stored procedure as Database default rather than individual column of tables in that procedure .

```
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between “SQL_Latin1_General_Pref_CP1_CI_AS” and “Latin1_General_CI_AS” in the equal to operation
```

I am getting collation conflict error as database server collation is different from database collation. The procedure is huge and I don't know on which table column conflict is occuring.

Is it even possible to assign collation for stored procedure such that all columns in that procedure have same collation?

Comment: I don't think comments like that are going to help your cause. I also don't believe you'd be able to do it on a connection wide basis. I think you best bet is to either run queries on the system tables to try and find out which columns contain that collation, and use those query results to see if you can see any that are seem like they might be used in your stored proc.

Comment: sorry i have deleted that comment

Comment: No probs. Try something like the following to see if it narrows down your issue; SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLLATION_NAME = 'SQL_Latin1_General_Pref_CP1_CI_AS'

Comment: Be careful when using temp tables, you want them to have the same collation as the database you are working. Temp tables use the database's server default collation. When creating a temp table explicitly set the collation. CREATE TABLE #TestTempTab
   (PrimaryKey int PRIMARY KEY,
    Col1 nchar COLLATE Estonian_CS_AS
   ).  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190920(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: @Daniel Cabral That was some really crucial info you provided me , i will be careful with temp tables now..Thanks a lot sir..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, collation is about how the textual data is stored within a table and is not at a stored procedure level.

Collation issues occur when textual data is compared from sources where the text collatation is not stored the same. (I am not talking about the data type of text, just string data)

Check the TSQL where clauses or table joins, this is the most common places where text compares occur. You can collate to the database default by using the collate function next to the compare area. For example

```
SELECT
c.CustomerID
FROM
dbo.Customer c
INNER JOIN dbo.CustomerLog cl on c.CustomerName = cl.LogEntry collate     
database_default
```

Depending on your circumstance this might not be possible but I always follows these rules.

- Choose the correct server default collation at install so the tempdb is created under the collation, when you create temp tables, these are created in the tempdb

- when creating tables do not specifiy the collation unless you have specific cause to